# How to increase amazon sqs queuing speed?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to queue thousands of messages to sqs. I'm looping through a for loop based on count and sending message to queue. Below is how my loop look

```
$sqsClient = AWS::createClient('sqs');
  for($i=0; $i<=$count;$i++){
    $sqsClient->sendMessage(array(
    'QueueUrl'    => 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz123/QueueName',
    'MessageBody' => 'Hello World',
    ));
  }
```

This way it is only queuing 10 messages per second. How can i increase it to queue 1000 messages per second.

Please Help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For increasing the messages delivery to 1000 messages/second you will have to use horizontal scaling for AWS SQS. Here is the developers guide for achieving horizontal scaling in AWS SQS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/throughput.html

If you are just using normal queue without scaling 10 messages/sec is only what you can achieve.

Comment: I did checked this article when it says horizontal scaling what does that mean? Do we need to set that anywhere while creating queue?

Comment: Try to implement and run the example step wise described in that article lots of concepts will be cleared. In horizontal scaling you increasing the number of your message producers and consumers. That setting is not done while creating a queue.

Answer (score 3):

SQS is a distributed system. Send messages in parallel from multiple threads/processes/machines to increase throughput.

Answer (score 0):

According to the "Amazon SQS Product Details" page (see https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/details/), it seems you're fixed to a limit of 10 requests per batch (see the "Functionality" section):

> Messages can be sent, received or deleted in batches of up to 10
>   messages or 256KB. Batches cost the same amount as single messages,
>   meaning SQS can be even more cost effective for customers that use
>   batching.

I also noticed in the FAQs that you may be limited to a fixed number of messages per month based on your tier (see the "Billing" section here: https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> The Amazon SQS free tier provides 1 million requests per month at no
>   charge. Many small scale applications may be able to operate entirely
>   within this free tier limit. Data transfer charges may still apply
>   (see Pricing). The free tier is a monthly offer. Free usage does not
>   accumulate across months.

If you're on their free tier and intend to send thousands of messages per second, I suspect you'll hit 1 million requests rather quickly.

I hope this information is helpful!

Comment: Hitting 1 million requests only means the subsequent requests are no longer free.  It's not a functional limit, only a billing rule.  Also, the original question is not sending batches -- just one message at a time, so there's a 10x potential improvement right there that's being overlooked.